# CMakeListsl.txt для linux и Windows

Tags: linux, windows, cmake, cmakelists

Недавно начал изучать cmake и интересно, можно ли в одном Cmakelists написать инструкцию для сборки и под Linux, и под windows?
И если можно то как это реализовать?
Или он реализует только под ту платформу, на которой он запущен?
Пишу на Linux

Answer (score 0):

еще как можно и даже нужно

```
if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL Windows)
.....
elseif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL Linux)
.....
endif()
```